# How to get content of Attached file lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning

I need to display content of attachment within iframe that is embedded in the particular sObject.

When you upload file from  `notes&Attachments` related list on salesforce classic its type is `attachment`
and i have hard coded link for displaying content of this attachment

> /servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='[id of attachment]'

But when i upload this file from lightning its type is `file`.

so is it possible to display content of `ContentVersion` I guess or what its type is in iframe in the same way as attachemnt in my example? 
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to query the contentLinkDocument records with the EntityId equal to the record Id .

And also ContentLinkDocument will give you Id of the content Document and you will need a query against content document to get the necessary file

```
SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '[RECORD ID]'
```

Then SOQL on ContentDocument

```
Select Id ,Title from ContentDocument Where ID In :[CONTENTDOCUMENTLIST]
```

Update

If you use Files or content related object there is a simple event with new lightning namespace which can be used

Here is a sample quick POC

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
  <aura:attribute name="contentId" type="String" default="069B00000015QMwIAM"/>
 <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Preview Reciept" onclick="{!c.preview }" />
```

Note that the default here is the Id of the content document .

The controller code for same is below

```
({
  preview : function(component, event, helper) {
   $A.get('e.lightning:openFiles').fire({
    recordIds: [component.get("v.contentId")]
   });
  }
})
```

Comment: in such a way i can only fetch ContentDocument object, but I need to render its content

Comment: rendering can be done via new event openfiles .You will fire that and a modal will render automatically .

Comment: unfortunately it does not resolve my problem, first I need to display content within iframe and also I can't open attachment in such a way only content document files, when I'm trying substitute id of attachemnt to default  value of attribute
 '<aura:attribute name="contentId" type="String" default="00P58000005CoxPEAS"/> '
i'm getting error

Comment: In lightning experience the attachment is stored in the contentversion object .So this is the content document Id

Comment: no, if file's  type is Attachment, we can't see it in Contentversion object

Comment: ok, I've added custom upload component for atttachment, are any similar method for delete attachments exist?