# Display an image stored in ContentDocument (in lightning experience)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, contentdocument

I'd like to display on a lightning component an image, that is stored in the ContentDocument object in lightning experience.

Before I used the Attachment in salesforce classic, with something like that : `<img src="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + a.image.Id}" alt=""/>`, but I need to use it in lighning experience.

I try to use [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147296/how-to-get-content-of-attached-file-lightning?rq=1) but I don't really understand how it works and I can't retrieve the image.

Comment: What is a.image.Id? can you post code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at the Data Model of the Content Object as mentioned in this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/14476/20830), it looks like you need to get `Id` of the `ContentVersion` which is tied to you the ContentDocument record. Also to display Contents, the relative url path should be in below format :

> /sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/contentversionid

**Sample code**

**myApp.app:**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" controller="TestCtrl">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 
    <aura:attribute name="contents" type="List" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="prefixURL" type="String" default="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.contents}" var="content">
        <img src="{!v.prefixURL + content.Id}" width="100" height="100"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

**controller.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp){
       var action = cmp.get("c.getContents");
       action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
           var state = response.getState();
           if(cmp.isValid() && state === 'SUCCESS') {
               cmp.set("v.contents", response.getReturnValue()); 
           }
       });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

})
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public class TestCtrl {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<ContentVersion> getContents() {
        Set<Id> contentIds = new Set<Id>();

        for (ContentDocument cont :[Select Id ,Title from ContentDocument]) {
            contentIds.add(cont.Id);
        }

        return [SELECT Id,Title FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN :contentIds];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use communities, the full url may be needed

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy I don't think we need full url, all we need is the NetworkPrefix along with relative url if we need to display it in community. I've seen a case where the image not getting displayed in Preview mode but it shows up in when the community is published.

Comment: Should this work with a pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use an  tag to show the image from ContentDocument. All you need to do is query and get the file ID from server.

**Apex class:**

```
return [Select Id ,Title from ContentDocument Where Name = :Your File Name LIMIT 1].Id;
```

You need to use the ID to form the URL in img tag like you used to do in VF.

**Lightning Component:**

```
<img src="{!'/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + v.fileId}" alt=""/>
```

Comment: It doesn't work either, I can't retrieve the image in my component, when I look at the image url I got that : https://mydomainname-ed.lightning.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file= so the Id of the image is not retrieved correctly

Comment: That depends how you are fetching the record id, you may want to update the question with your apex side code and JS controller.