# Content details display issue in lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

- Library contains contents . Each content contains tags. One tag may link to many contents.
- Whenever use clicks particular tag i need to display contents. After clicking contents I am trying to display related documents.
- In the code,passing content document Id for displaying documents but itsnot working.

Approach followed:

- Even I have tried passing Content version Id also its still not working
- Tried with Community url also
- Getting ***broken image in my case (trying  for Community)***

  ```
   <aura:component  implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
   access="global">
      <aura:attribute name="id" type="Id"/> 
        <aura:attribute name="ContentIds" type="Id" 
  default="0690n000000QcF6"/> 

     <aura:attribute name="prefixURL" type="String" 
   default="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/"/>
   <img src="{!v.prefixURL+v.ContentIds}" width="100" height="100"/>
  </aura:component>
  ```

I referred below stack exchange code, tried in my org its working for both community & app builder

[Display an image stored in ContentDocument (in lightning experience)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169102/display-an-image-stored-in-contentdocument-in-lightning-experience/169132)

Problem in the code: ***If attachment is pdf,itsnot working!!***

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution finally.

Using lightning Tile card it works

```
 <lightning:fileCard fileId="{!v.ContentdocIds}"/>
```

Here ContentdocIds - ContentDocumentId