# Display Salesforce File in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, files

I see from [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169102/display-an-image-stored-in-contentdocument-in-lightning-experience) question that you can display an image in a lightning component. Will this work for a pdf file? Using the exact same code, it doesn't appear so.

I did try using [lightning:fileCard](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileCard/specification) to display my pdf, but it's too small. I'd like it to take up 40% of this modal I'm working on. It doesn't appear to get any bigger, even when I use [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/sizing/#8-Column-Span)

[image]

Here is what my markup looks like, if needed:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
<div class="slds-size_2-of-8">
    <!-- left blank intentionally -->

</div>
<div class="slds-size_3-of-8">
    <!-- form stuff -->

</div>

<div class="slds-size_3-of-8">
        <lightning:fileCard fileId="{!v.rxImage.ContentDocumentId}" 
                            description="{!v.rxImage.ContentDocument.Title}"
                            />              
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible way to display pdf in frame with the desired width and height is by creating a public link of your file.

```
<iframe src="https://<mydomain>/sfc/p/B0000000Tmi4/a/B0000000CcRD/47Yen7wPwwcwvQ1pNAquq7vX0tb1Y2MztsCy2iqNJF0"
            width="100%"
            height="500px"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the open-source PDF.js library.  With this library, you get a lot of nice Acrobat-like features for navigating between pages, zooming, etc.

[Download the example ZIP file here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Setup-pdf.js-in-a-website) and extract it.  You can remove everything except the build and web directories, then zip it back up.  Upload as a static resource, e.g. "PDFjs".

Have an iframe like this in your component:

```
<iframe aura:id="pdfFrame" src="/resource/PDFjs/web/viewer.html" class="pdfFrame" ></iframe>
```

To pass a PDF in, use the following code in your controller/helper:

```
var pdfFrame = component.find('pdfFrame');
pdfFrame.getElement().contentWindow.postMessage(YOUR_BASE64_ENCODED_PDF_DATA_HERE,'*');
```

Comment: How do you reference the html from the static resource?

Comment: The HTML from the static resource is referenced in the src attribute on the iframe.

Comment: @TylerZika Hi, were you able to display your file, I am stuck in something similar, if you can update anything on this.

Comment: @user905 are you trying to display a pdf as well?